# How to change background style (css) in Leaflet layers control

Tags: css, leaflet

I turned off the "layers control" background in leaflet.css, but the black frame remained. How to disable it in css? I will be grateful for the answer.
I added parameters: outline: none; box-shadow: none;
border: none, but they do not work here.

```
/* layers control */
.leaflet-control-layers {
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.0); 
    background: solid rgba(0,0,0,0.0); 
    border-radius: 4px; 
    }
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle { 
    background-image: url("../../images/text/0_Filter.png");
    width: 106px;
    height: 22px;
    } 
.leaflet-retina .leaflet-control-layers-toggle { 
    background-image: url("../../images/text/0_Filter.png");
    background-size: 106px 22px;
    }
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers-toggle { 
    width: 106px;
    height: 22px;
    outline: none; /* test dont work*/
    box-shadow: none; /* test dont work*/
    border: none /* test dont work*/
    }
.leaflet-control-layers .leaflet-control-layers-list,
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
    display: none;
    }
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded .leaflet-control-layers-list {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    }
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded {
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 6px;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff; 
    }
.leaflet-control-layers-scrollbar {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-right: 5px;
    }
.leaflet-control-layers-selector {
    margin-top: 2px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    }
.leaflet-control-layers label {
    display: block;
    }
.leaflet-control-layers-separator {
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 5px -10px 5px -6px;
    }
```

Comment: What did you try? Provide some codes to understand correctly.

Comment: I need layer control without background, I turned it off in the css, but the black stroke remained. I did not find it in "leaflet.css".
Screen: breamap.hostronavt.ru/images/layer_control.jpg
Thanks for your help...

Comment: Try this `outline: none; box-shadow: none; border: none` to remove that black frame.

Comment: I added parameters: outline: none; box-shadow: none;
border: none, but they do not work here. The css code of "layers control" added above to the question.

Comment: Could you provide live site url or screen screen shot of devtools in chrome?

Comment: Top right of the map: http://breamap.hostronavt.ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to live site, there's a border in the wrapper of that `<a>` tag.

You need to remove that border like below:

```
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers {
  border: none;
}
```